# Expressing a recurrence relation as a polynomial

Tags: number-theory

> Let us define $u_0 = 0, u_1 = 1$ and for $n \geq 0$, $u_{n+2} = au_{n+1}+bu_n$, $a$ and $b$ being positive integers. Express $u_n$ as a polynomial in $a$ and $b$. Prove the result: Given that $b$ is prime, prove that $b$ divides $a(u_b-1)$.

How do we deal with the case that the characteristic equation has a double root? We can deal with the other case by just solving the recurrence, but how should we do it in the general case?

Comment: Since $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, the characteristic equation cannot have a double root.

Comment: @egreg I get $$u_n = \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+4b}}\right)\left(\dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+4b}}\right)\left(\dfrac{a-\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}\right)^n.$$

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But that's not what the problem asks you.

Comment: @egreg So do I have to use some other method than solving the recurrence? If so, what method should I use?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you have a double root, your solution is in the following form

$$
u_n = (\alpha+n\beta)r^n
$$

Here you have 
$$
r = \frac{a}{2}
$$
and
$$
\alpha = 0 \quad \beta = \frac{2}{a}
$$
Hence
$$
u_n = n (\frac{a}{2})^{n-1} \quad n\geq 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if we find a pattern.
\begin{align}
u_0&=0\\
u_1&=1\\
u_2&=au_1+bu_0=a\\
u_3&=au_2+bu_1=a^2+b\\
u_4&=au_3+bu_2=a(a^2+b)+ab=a^3+2ab\\
u_5&=au_4+bu_3=a(a^3+2ab)+b(a^2+b)=a^4+3a^2b+b^2
\end{align}

It seems reasonable to assert that, for $n\ge2$,
$$
u_n=a^{n-1}+bf_n(a,b)
$$
where $f_n(a,b)$ is a polynomial in $a$ and $b$. This can be proved by induction (do it).

Finally we have
$$
a(u_b-1)=a(a^{b-1}+bf_b(a,b)-1)=(a^b-a)+bf_b(a,b)
$$
Can you prove this is divisible by $b$, when $b$ is prime?